# Choosing numbers and full points from a string

Tags: python, python-re

I wrote the following code to choose the numbers from a string. I only get integers and I'd like to get the decimals too.

```
def vreplace_chars(third): 
                vlist_of_numbers = re.findall(r'\d+',third)
                vresult_number = '---'.join(vlist_of_numbers)
                return vresult_number
            number=vreplace_chars(imgchar)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change a regex to optionally include decimal part
`\d+(?:.\d+)?`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your pattern. Maybe something like that should help you. For instance, here decimal can be capture with "," or "." :

```
import re
def vreplace_chars(third, pattern= r"(\d+(\,|.\d+)*)"):
        vresult_number = '---'.join([x[0] for x in re.findall(pattern, third)])
        return vresult_number
  
>>> vreplace_chars("okok9.0,5689.0")
'9.0,---5689.0'
```

If you want to find decimal with "." only, define pattern as follows :

```
pattern= r"(\d+(.\d+)*)"
```